# How to add a number to an integer

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsinteger

I am trying to make a NSInteger being abel to contain a number while the app is runing and that I can add numbers to that NSInteger hers my code

```
// in the .h
NSInteger *count;
// in the .m
count = 0;
```

Then I save count in NSUserDefaults like so

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:count forKey:@"key"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

In the next view after calling NSUserDefaults I do this

```
count + 4;
```

The problem is that in the end I always get zero.

Comment: `count += 4` looks like what you need

Comment: can i also do that with any other number?

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a reference to NSInteger, so `NSInteger *count;` should be `NSInteger count;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSInteger` is a primitive type, not an object type. So you don't want to use a pointer to `NSInteger`, but directly `NSInteger`:

```
// in the .h
NSInteger count;
// in the .m
count = 0;
```

And to increase it:

```
count += 4;
```

Comment: ah man thanks you are a hero i had to finish this today really helped